# Trying to switch the formula

Tags: education

I don't really know what this thing that I am doing is called, hence the reason I am asking here and not googling. I have a formula $0.5x(x + 1) = y$. And I am trying to convert it to a function which provides the x value based on the y value. I have the following function at the moment $x = (y / 0.5)/x - 1$. What do I have to do to remove the x variable on the right-hand side? Can you also tell me what this thing that I am doing is called so I'll have easier time googling.

Comment: You have $y=f(x)$ and you are trying to find the inverse of the function $f$.  However, I do not understand your formula.  Your definition tells us that $x^2+x-2y=0$ and you can use the quadratic formula to find $x$ as a function of $y$ (note that there may sometimes be two values of $x$ that work for a single $y$).

Comment: What you are doing is called "finding the inverse of the function".